# How to take input from a separate file and send the output to another file in node.js?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have two files. One is `input.html` and another one is `output.html`. I am taking input from `input.html` and I want to print output data to `output.html`. How will I do this?

Please help Me.

**input.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <style type="text/css">

        #chatlog{ list-style:none;}
        #chatlog li{ border-bottom:2px solid #ddd; padding:10px 0}

        </style>

            <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var socketio = io.connect("127.0.0.1:1337");

    function sendMessage() {
        var msg = document.getElementById("message_input").value;
        socketio.emit("message_to_server", { message : msg});
    }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <input type="text" id="message_input"/>
            <button onclick="sendMessage()">send</button>

        </body>
    </html>
```

**output.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <style type="text/css">

        #chatlog{ list-style:none;}
        #chatlog li{ border-bottom:2px solid #ddd; padding:10px 0}
         </style>
     <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
              <script src="../main.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">

       var socketio = io.connect("127.0.0.1:1337");
    socketio.on("message_to_client", function(data) {
                    alert(gbldata);
        /*document.getElementById("chatlog").innerHTML = ("<hr/>" +
        data['message'] + document.getElementById("chatlog").innerHTML);*/
        var rediv =document.createElement('li');
        var retext= document.createTextNode(data['message']+"coming new call");
        rediv.appendChild(retext);
        var mul = document.getElementById('chatlog');
        //mul.appendChild(rediv);
        mul.insertBefore(rediv, mul.childNodes[0]);

        })
           </script>

        </head>
        <body>

            <ul id="chatlog">

            </ul>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**server.js**

```
    var http = require('http'),
        fs = require('fs');

    var app = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
        fs.readFile("client.html", 'utf-8', function (error, data) {
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            response.write(data);
            response.redirect('output.html');

      });
    }).listen(1337);
    console.log('Server running at http://localhost:1337/');

    var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

    io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
        socket.on('message_to_server', function(data) {
            io.sockets.emit("message_to_client",{ message: data["message"] });
            console.log(data["message"]);

        });
    });
```

Comment: Please edit your question to be legible.

Comment: Looks like you have already tried something but doesn't work. Can you highlight what you tried and where it is failing (error message if any etc.)